# How many TCP handshaking and teardown have been accomplished using wireshark?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I ran wireshark for a while and opened a few webpages,now my class assignment is asking me to find out the number of TCP handshaking and teardown accomplished. Can you suggest commands or filters to find these out?

Comment: Homework questions shouldn't be answered completely, then you learn better if you spend some time sincerely investigating by yourself. TCP says connections are opened with SYN/SYN-ACK sequences, and closed with FIN-ACK/FIN sequences. Try building something around this.

Answer (score 0):

You should try sincerely. Similar answer is available on Wireshark (Question & Answer)  page.

TCP uses a three-way handshake to establish a reliable connection. The connection is full duplex, and both sides synchronize (SYN) and acknowledge (ACK) each other. The exchange of these four flags is performed in three steps—SYN, SYN-ACK, and ACK.

Refer below link, which gives info about filters:
https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/26174/filter-for-detecting-the-third-packet-in-a-3-way-handshake

To filter TCP SYN flags use “tcp.flags.syn == 1 && tcp.flags.ack == 0”

[image]

At the bottom of Wireshark tool, you can see the total number of TCP SYN flags, in my case 160 SYN flags are filtered.

[image]

Similar way you can  filter TCP SYN-ACK flags use “ tcp.flags.syn == 1 && tcp.flags.ack == 1”

[image]

At the bottom of Wireshark tool, you can see the total number of TCP SYN-ACK flags, in my case 109 SYN flags are filtered.

[image]